# publishing html files

Tags: google-app-engine

Hie

I am generated html documents using a google text doc as template (reading it using gdata apis and then doing some text manipulation). 
Now, I want to publish these documents somewhere so that I can refer to others giving the url of the document (which means it would be publicly accessible).

Any suggestions on how do i go about it? Like where should i host these? and how to do that in java from my google app engine app

just a little background: I am actually fetching the template from google doc where i created it and then using the gdata apis to fetch this template in gae code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also use the [BlobStore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/). Is cheaper to store this kind of data on the Blobstore than doing it on DataStore. You cam also try the new [Google Cloud Storage](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/getting-started).

Comment: is it for java as well? the example on page seems to be with python https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/hellogooglestorage

Comment: hie thanks for replying. so what are the pros and cons using blobstore versus google cloud storage?

Answer (score 2):

Why bother with the complexity of Amazon S3 when Google Appengine has everything you need to serve HTML files included?
For small apps, using just Google AppEngine you likely wont incur any charges, but if you start using S3 even your small app will cost you in storage and bandwidth fees.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest going with S3. I never tried to manipulate S3 buckets from App Engine, but I assume it shouldn't be any harder that it would be from any other server that allows outbound HTTP requests. Google also provides an S3-like storage service and you should take traffic into consideration when picking one over the other. IIRC, there are others who provide S3-like APIs.

I assume your HTML files aren't huge enough to hit any outbound HTTP request limitation.

Comment: yeah my html files are not huge and currently not expecting to have to o many to store.  do u have more details on google's s3?

Answer (score 1):

Why not store them in the DataStore? if they are not huge, they could be stored as  DataStore items with their URL as the key_name, and then just create a handler to display them when a request is made. use Caching to ensure you dont burn too many CPU cycles serving them up.

Much simpler to keep it all under GAE than to try to mix in S3 etc.